# Using External SSD with Maui

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have been developing Android apps since last year and would love to move over to Maui. I currently have a HDD Drive in my PC and an external Samsung Drive. I have all my Xamarin Forms projects on the SSD. I tried setting up a Maui app on the SSD but it was saying I'm using the wrong file system. I am aware of how to change it however I had a question. If I copy all my VS files onto my hard drive, format the SSD and cut and paste the files back, will all of my app publication keys ECT work , cheers :).

Comment: Are you trying to store your project files on an external drive? That is possible, but it's much safer to store it somewhere you have full version control such as git. Moving files a lot may corrupt them.

Comment: Hey, so I would only move them once to reformat my external SSD and then move them back once Ive changed my file format, I was just wondering if all the app signing keys ect used in xamarin forms would be okay with this? cheers